# Unrecognized configuration section system.web/protocols. Error

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am getting    Unrecognized configuration section system.web/protocols error. What might be the reason?. Is identity impresonate is not allowed inside system.web tag..?? Please see my web.config file below for more details.

```
<system.web>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="admin" password="adminpwd"/>
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI" tagPrefix="asp"/>     
    </controls>
  </pages>
  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="false">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>      
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1500" maxRequestLength="80000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="80000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="5000" enableKernelOutputCache="true" enableVersionHeader="true" requireRootedSaveAsPath="true" enable="true" shutdownTimeout="90" delayNotificationTimeout="5" waitChangeNotification="0" maxWaitChangeNotification="0" enableHeaderChecking="true" sendCacheControlHeader="true" apartmentThreading="false"/>
</system.web>
```

This is the error message

```
Error   102 Unrecognized configuration section system.web/protocols. (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config line 297)
```

Also the error ocurred when i copied the source code from another machine.

Comment: Can you check that Which section is declared at line 297 of web.config "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config" file?

Comment: There is one protocol tag at line no: 297.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed.I have looked at c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config and NOT the project web.config file and only removed the protocols tag which was empty (I really don't understand why!!!)  I have not added any single line to the project Web.config file.  I hope this will help anyone there having the same problem.